# Is it a C# bug?

Tags: c#

The following piece of code gives compile-time error in VS2010:

`Use of unassigned local variable 'error'`

```
leveldb_memory error;

try
{
    return leveldb_open(options, name, out error); // <== Notice `out error`
}
finally
{
    Validate(error); // <== Use of unassigned local variable 'error'
}
```

It doesn't seem correct, is there a way to overcome this error without modifying the code?

---

**Edit**

Oh well, it is not a C# bug... :(

Comment: well, you aren't assigning anything to it...

Comment: To answer the question in the title, no, no it is not a c# bug

Comment: yes, but it's not in the scope of the finally. What if it would fails in the function call ? the error will just stay unassigned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`error` does not have an initial value. And it still won't have if `leveldb_open` throws an exception before setting it.

So using `error` without setting a value to it can lead to an error.

If `leveldb_memory` is a nullable type you can init it to `null`:

```
leveldb_memory error = null;
```

Answer (score 9):

No, `leveldb_open` could throw an exception which would cause `error` not to be set.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the variable Error is never assigned a value. I'm not sure how else to answer this question? It's not a c# bug thats for sure.

Comment: It will be assigned a value if `leveldb_open` returns successfully

Answer (score 1):

```
leveldb_memory error = default( levelldb_memory );
try {
    return leveldb_open( options, name, out error );
} finally {
    Validate( error );
}
```

`default` creates object from type without run on it constructor.
When you doing something in `try` block that doesn't effect at what after it,
Because the code can caught exception and don't assign error.

BTW it's can call `Validate` on empty object. But the `default` part is to hide the error.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize `error` variable before you can pass it to the method.

So just do `error = null` and the compiler will be happy.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a C# error (-:
although you use `out error` which allow the function to assign to `error` no one promise you there is an assignment inside. therefore you must check it yourself...

Comment: -1: That's not correct. `out` forces an assignment inside the method.